# PHPUnit in docker: no colors in PowerShell

Tags: docker, powershell, phpunit

How can I get colored output when running PHPUnit inside a Docker container from Windows PowerShell?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.0-cli-alpine
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
COPY . /usr/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/myapp
RUN composer update
CMD [ "php", "./vendor/bin/phpunit", "--testsuite", "Default"]
```

phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Default">
            <file>tests/FooTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

When I run the docker image from Powershell, PHPUnit outputs plain white text only, no red/green bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the Dockerfile CMD to

```
CMD [ "php", "./vendor/bin/phpunit", "--colors=always", "--testsuite", "Default"]
```

... and it worked. For some reason, the setting from the phpunit.xml is not applied in this environment.